# How do I deal with postdoc acceptances that come in before my preferred institution makes its decision known?

Tags: career-path, job-search, postdocs, early-career

I will graduate soon from the doctoral program. I will apply for multiple postdoc positions. The results of the one that I really think is great for my career will be probably announced later than the others. If I accept an earlier offer, and later learn that I could also get the one I desire the most, then I will really regret. However, I don't want to risk by refusing an early offer, since at the end I may get nothing.

Do you have any recommendations for such situations? Have you ever experienced this dilemma? How did you manage it?

Comment: Related at Workplace.SE: [How do I coordinate the process of pursuing multiple job opportunities at the same time?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/111/17125)

Comment: The same question could be asked about faculty positions.

Comment: You can always ask for (and often get) additional time from the place that has made an offer, while letting your preferred place know that you have a deadline and they'd better hurry up.  That worked for me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is an typical situation in application process with no perfect solution available. I is totally ok to apply for several positions at a time. The institutions are also talking to several applicants in parallel. But after signing a contract, it is not a nice gesture to revoke this w/o reason (even if notice periods would allow this legally). The institute has set trust in you and canceled the application of others. How would you feel if, after you have signed at an institute and canceled other applications, they would say : "Oh sorry, we got the confirmation from somebody which is more suitable to our business targets. Thanks for your time and good luck."

Below are some ideas on how to handle the dilemma. It is up to you, which one you want to follow:

- Accept that in life you have to make decisions at time when you don't have all pros and cons available. It's is not like finding a solution to an exam, where the data available clearly defines which answer is *correct* and which is *wrong*.
- Accept that, even if if you would have all offers available at the same time, you cannot say which offer is the best. Many unexpected events might happen at one position or the other: Your project might get canceled during your work. Your professor might change department. You might meet your future spouse.
- If you are really sure which is the best position for you, but the confirmation from this position has still not arrived: Contact this potential employer and explain your situation. You are really interested in this position, but you have also agreements from other institutes so you need to make about the alternatives an decision. Is it possible for your target employer to give you an confirmation earlier? If the employer is really interested in you, they will try to shorten the decision time. Otherwise there is the risk that they lose you.
- After signing a contract, withdraw all applications to other institutes. So you save them work. Additionally you avoid you dilemma, when you get an positive reply, but have signed already elsewhere.
- Attention: Only be sure to have a job after you have signed a contract. Don't rely on verbal promises only. Things might change easily: The project start might be delayed by 1 year. Or the nephew of the CEO might be interested in the position ...
- Asking for time (e.g. 1 weekend) to think it over an recent contract is ok. But at durations longer than 1 week, the employer might become impatient.
- A bit more time can be gained, if you ask for some small modifications on an proposed contract. The employer might need some time (eg. 1 week) to issue a new contract. Anyhow this point (and the previous one) shall not be exploited too much. The employer might get the impression that you are not really interested and hire an other candidate in the meantime.
- If possible, you can try to reduce the risk a bit, by smart timing of the applications. First send them out to one or two institutions which are not in your main target area. The benefit here, is that you have the opportunity to get some more training in the application process. You become more confident in interview situation. Second try your number 1 choice. You can hope for earlier feedback if there is an opportunity for you. With some delay you could contact departments which are a good fallback solution, althrough not the main target. The idea here is that you are not forced to early to decide to take or leave an offer here. If your number one declines, you might get some positive feedback from these good fallback solutions later. 
  Of course this strategy has to be adapted to time restrictions, and the application deadlines for the adverticed positions.
- Career is not only defined by your first job. Of course this first job already gives you an direction in industry you will develop. Further corrections here might be energy and time consuming. But the final result, if you become an owner of an multinational enterprise, an university professor, or simply an employe w/o significant career step depends mostly on personality.
- Potential employers prefer candidates who appear to be authentic. Don't try to play to much games with them.
- Trust your gut feeling.

Comment: *Unlike* in science?

Comment: Yes. What I want to say is: At university you learn to analyse problems, by deeply analysing everything which influences the outcome. Publications should only include statements which are completly water-proof.    Also at exams you are drilled to find the clearly defined `correct` answer.    In contrary in life there is no exact `correct`and `wrong`. I admid that this statement is a bit provoking and simplifying. I know that during research you also have to make decision based on incomplete data. But I hope you get the main idea what I wanted to say.

Comment: I have edited my answer a bit in order to be more clear.

Comment: @BerndGit, I find many people in academia suggesting/recommending what you did to the OP (in summary, one shouldn't revoke a signed contract for another better offer). I wonder why different standards for academia and industry with respect to free-will/free-market? In most countries, including the US, the employers can not bind the employees even after signing a contract. There can't be any legal reasons for such advises, except for some specific cases. Are you saying that the OP should still go to an institute that offered 40K/year salary even if s\he later on gets an offer of 70K/year?

Comment: @John: Even in industry, it's definitely frowned upon to back out of a signed contract. I would never hire or recommend someone who I knew had done it, and I would never apply to or recommend a company that I knew had done it. I think the difference is just that in academia, "frowned upon" carries much more weight, since it's a much smaller community, with references and word-of-mouth playing a much larger role in hiring.

Comment: @John: I completly agree with ruakh.

Comment: BerndGit and @ruakh, in the industry, you can almost always manage to get next jobs if you have necessary skills. I wasnt usually pressed to provide references from particular set of people when I used to jump around companies in my non academia days, nor did leaving one job for a better paying job was ever considered immoral. If anything,  it is considered an obvious decision ther. In academia, in most desciplines, it is a buyers' market due to so less no of available jobs. The job seekers have to suck it up to any whimsical beliefs of the hiring sides, to survive.

Comment: As long as the agrement does not specifically bind the employees to the employer, then it is simply against the law to bind the employee. Yes, you can start bad mouthing against such an employee who went away from you because he/she was thinking about their own family more than you, but I wonder who would look a looser here?!

Comment: @John: It is up to you, to decide how you want to deal with people in your life (as long as you stay within legal limits). However you might also experience consequences of your actions which you might not like (which are also legally ok).

Comment: @BerndGit, completely agreed. I just wanted to convey that the same applies to the employers too! At least in the industry where the power is not too much at the employers' side. Eg they wont get good candidates any more if the employers become so touchy about employes' natural decisions. In academia, because of the unfortunate power imbalance and some over authoratarion tenured profs, the employees may have to decide between personal good and suck it up.

Comment: I also personally think that your answer should clearly state that as long as there is nothing explicitly binding clause in the contract, the employer can not prevent the employee choosing a better offer, and that your answer is from the 'ethical/moral' point of view. Don't get me wrong. I seriously think that your answer is similar to what I hear from some tenured profs at various departments and hence is highly valuable to understand one particular perspective on the issue.

Comment: @John I think you're missing an important point about academic employment, which is that (in the US) it is heavily concentrated in one particular time of the year (roughly mid-winter, for starting the next fall).  In industry, if you lose a new hire, it's a pain, but you have just as good expectation of finding a good candidate one month later as you did in the first search (to first approximation).  If a postdoc accepts a job in January and changes their mind in April, a school can't go to its second or third-choice: they've been off the market for months.

Comment: @John and no one new will be available until a year later.  So having a candidate back out after accepting is much more disruptive; that's why there's such a norm against it.

Comment: @BenWebster, I agree to your point. It can certainly be disruptive up to certain extent to the universities. And I would not like to let any university be in such a situation. However, the worst disruption of this may be to find a replacement for the classes in the following fall semester. Given that the employers have full summer and potential adjuncts, this shouldn't be unmanageable. On the other hand, again, you are mentioning a situation from the employer's point of view and not from the employee's point of view which is the whole point of this discussion.

Comment: Regarding the disruption in the research goals of the PI who wanted to hire the postdoc. This becomes more problematic to the PI. But then the advice that 'This is not the end of your life. You need to move on.' would also apply to the PIs. The practice of preaching postdocs/new hires that they should stick to the first offer they have accepted no matter what is nothing but to protect the convenience of the employers here. The root to the fact that such practices and preaches continue lies in the bad job market in academia. In all other fields, arbitrage is a natural and obvious thing.

Comment: **Please take extended discussion to [chat].**

Answer (score 25):

This can be difficult. If you get an offer with an uncomfortable deadline, I would recommend bringing it to the attention of departments which you prefer (and/or individual faculty at those departments).

This is not guaranteed to push them to make a faster decision, but it could.

Answer (score 19):

It is perfectly ethical to *apply* to several positions at the same time. It is a different thing if you *accept* and then decline later on (as they may plan for you to come at that stage); still it happens, but it's not ideal.

The fairest solution is, once you get an acceptance from the first batch, to ask them to wait for a certain period - they may not like it, but you agreeing to getting interviewed is not a promise to join them and they have the option to deadline you if they need a quick decision. If you are strong, they may be more flexible in that respect.

You will not get entirely around this dilemma of balancing your and their legitimate interests.

Comment: "*Ask* them to wait" is spot on -- if they want (or even need) an answer immediately they can tell you.  You might want to use an approach like "time to consider" rather than "there's another job I fancy more".

Answer (score 10):

I can answer this question from my experience
of applying for multiple postdoc positions
and accepting one of two offers.

A few years ago, I applied to around 6 postdoc positions.
The professor for one of the positions gave me an interview,
and gave me an exploding offer for position A with a one week deadline.

At the time, I felt that position A was the best fit for me,
so I was going to take the offer
and just withdraw from the other positions.
However, my PhD advisor advised me
to follow up with my other applications, just in case.
Upon his urging,
I sent a follow-up e-mail to each of the other positions
to which I applied, basically saying

> I was wondering if there are any updates regarding my postdoc application? I would like to work with you, so I wanted to let you know that I just received an offer for another postdoc position, which I have to decide to accept by *the date*.

After I sent these e-mails, a few of the faculty told me that
they would not be able to make a decision quickly
and so would not be able to give an offer.
One of the faculty decided to give me an interview,
and eventually gave me an offer which I accepted.

I am thankful for my PhD advisor's advice
which led me to a position B which I felt was
a better fit for me than position A.
I am also thankful that the faculty at position A
gave me one week which was a reasonable time frame
for me to contact the other positions
and to work out an offer which I eventually accepted.

**TL;DR**
When you receive a firm offer,
you can politely let the other recruiters/faculty know
that you need to make a decision soon.
If they are interested in you,
that may spur them to act more quickly
to give you and interview and offer.

Answer (score 3):

*NOTE*: I do not have any experience in applying a postdoc position; but this comes to my mind:

I logically guess that, there should be some time between the date that the university calls applicant and tells him that he passed evaluation tests and his application is accepted and the latest date that the applicant can inform the university or research institute that he will accept and register for his position.

I recommend you to take care of these dates and time gaps.

Maybe, when you are in the gap time that you can register for another institute where you are less interested in working; the more preferred one inform you that you are accepted and you may register there.

Another option may be contacting the institute you are applying to or the professor with whom you will be working (your mentor) and ask whether you can delay your registration/attendance or not. They may assist their applicant in some emergency conditions.

*Please note that, I am not really sure whether it is ethical or not to decline your application after it is accepted by a university; or whether it is ethical to apply for more than one institute at a time. However, I have the sense that it is applicant's future and opportunities, and he can apply to many job positions simultaneously.*