# I recieved a postdoc offer but I still have another postdoc interview. Should I accept or cancel?

Tags: postdocs, job-search, job, interview

This month, I have number of postdocs interviews planned. I just passed the first one and I did really good, the PI just send me an informal email telling me that I did really good and I should expect a decision tomorrow (I just got interviewed the day before). So, I'm expecting good news.

Here's the issue, I still have an interview by the end of the month that I am looking for, and another one at a another university 4 weeks from now. For this last interview, I really like the research project they're working on and my strong skills are the essential skills they're looking for. So, I'm confident about this last interview.

I don't want to decide anything until I pass these 3 interviews, but the committee in the first interview is moving way too quickly for me. So, I don't know what to do.

On the scenario where I received an offer from the first interview tomorrow or early next week. Should I cancel the interviews that I am actually looking for? Is it acceptable to accept the offer and still have the other interviews? (You know where I'm going with this)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I deal with postdoc acceptances that come in before my preferred institution makes its decision known?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/62298/how-do-i-deal-with-postdoc-acceptances-that-come-in-before-my-preferred-institut)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to accept an offer the minute it's given. Thank the PI for the offer and let them know you are waiting to hear the outcome of other interviews before making your final decision. Given them the approximate date that you will be able to let them know your choice. Everyone understands that having multiple applications in the pipeline is common. As long as you don't keep them waiting for months, you should be fine (you can ask if the PI has a date by which they want your decision, too).

Under no circumstances should you accept an offer but still go for an interview somewhere else. That is a waste of everyone's time, and unfair to those candidates interviewing for the second position who actually intend to take it if offered.

Comment: I understand, I completely agree with you. But I just want to know what should I do in this situation. For my particular case, the postdocs I am looking for are at least 2-3 weeks from now. Is it possible to ask them to wait that long?

Comment: You can always ask ;) Given that "they" often take months to even decide who is interviewed, I personally think "we" should be allowed to take 1-2 months to take a decision as well, and wait for all outcomes of our applications. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be the case in the real world...