# Does it look bad to go to a campus interview at one university after accepting a TT position at another university?

Tags: etiquette, job-search, faculty-application, tenure-track, interview

I currently accepted a TT position in a Canadian university (let's call it "Univ. A"). I have now a on campus interview (again for TT position) at a more prestigious US university (call it "Univ. B"). Now I have a dilemma, about whether to go on campus interview at "Univ. B".

If I go to campus interview (which is likely public info) at "Univ. B", how "unacceptable" is in the eyes of other universities? ("Univ. A" will surely not be happy)

Comment: yes continuing to interview after accepting an offer will annoy the place you accepted an offer from. If you are confident you can not interview secretly I suggest notifying Univ. B and asking to change the purpose of your visit from "job interview" to "research seminar"

Comment: Your question is really do I risk a long distance relationship and take the chance they find someone else, or do I join them and suffer if it goes south : good luck.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you have already received and accepted an offer of a position at University A. Then you should inform University B (and any other universities you've applied to) about this fact and withdraw your application(s) there.  (You could, in the same message, inform University B of your continuing interest in working with some of their faculty, even if the collaboration has to be via email or skype.)

Comment: I removed the details about A and B from your post, as they are not relevant to the question of "how will this look to other universities."

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38040/what-is-the-recommended-option-for-a-faculty-applicant-after-accepting-an-offer/38050#38050

Answer (score 2):

> Does it look bad etc. ?

Yes, it looks bad - although it's not clear it is actually noticeable, see below.

Also, it depends on what you mean by "accepted":

- Did you only say you want to accept the offer over a phone conversation?
- Was there a formal letter of offer?
- Did you formally accept the offer somehow?
- Was there work on a draft contract, or negotiation of employment conditions?
- Was there a final contract?
- Did the university sign the contract?
- Did you sign the contract?
- Has some time passed since your signature, during which University A may have been making plans relying on your starting to work there?
- Were you assigned specific duties such as teaching, committee memberships etc?

The more "Yes"es on this list, the worse it is. If it's just the first item, though, I wouldn't even say it's that bad that you're proceeding with another interview.

> "Univ. A" will surely not be happy

It is not necessarily the case that University A will know, or can know, that you've gone and interviewed at University B. After all, visiting a university does not necessarily taking an interview; so unless they're in contact with whoever is interviewing at University B, and those people feel like sharing this information with them - it's not clear University A will be any the wiser.

**Note that I'm not suggesting you actually use this fact to hide what you're doing from University A.**

And a second note: Some people hold partial tenured positions in more than one university; others hold a tenured position in one university and a "visiting professor" or some such position at another. You could possibly make your interview at B be about that.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the answer all your points are "yes" in my case, so it may look bad. "Univ. A" also spent their money to get me there (sorting out immigration stuff). I forgot to mention that my TT position at "Univ. A" starts now (Jan 2018), while the interview at "Univ. B" is for a TT position starting in Sept. 2018.